# Extracting thumbnails with mplayer result in grey images

Tags: mplayer, video-thumbnails

I'm trying to extract thumbnails using mplayer with this command:

```
mplayer -nosound -ss 1 -vf screenshot -frames 1 -vo png:z=9 jump.mpg
```

The problem is that it results in an almost grey image.

If I now try and execute the command:

```
mplayer -ss 1 jump.mpg
```

Then the video plays back skipping the first second (as expected), but the first second of the playback is mostly grey. Technically, I think it displays the diff to the previous frame, until it gets to a key frame, where the whole frame is encoded in the video.

Now the question is:
How do I force mplayer to seek to a key frame, so I avoid this grey image when extracting?

I found the option **-hr-seek off**, which sounds like it should do the right thing, but it doesn't.

Comment: OK, my solution was to simply extract 20 thumbnails and use the last one of those 20 extracted thumbnails. Once a key frame is hit the following thumbnails look correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use mplayer2, the seek problem is solved. I tested myself:

http://www.mplayer2.org/differences/

on debian/ubuntu just install via `apt-get install mplayer2`